# Can I force GCC Mips to generate integer multiplication instructions instead of shifts for known numbers?

Tags: c, gcc, mips, compiler-flags

This code here

```
u32 foo;
foo = foo*11
```

Naturally compiles assembly along the lines of

```
lui t3, $hi(foo)
LW t0, $lo(foo)(t3)
sll t1, t0, $3
sll t2, t0, $1
add t1, t1, t2
add t0, t0, t1
sw t0, $lo(foo)(t3)
```

However, due to the architecture I am working with (N64), I'd like it to compile into

```
lui t3, $hi(foo)
LW t0, $lo(foo)(t3)
addiu t1, r0, $b
mult t0, t1
mflo t0
sw t0, $lo(foo)(t3)
```

Can I somehow beat GCC into submission here?

Comment: Why is this actually an improvement for this particular incarnation of MIPS?

Comment: change compile options to -Os https://godbolt.org/z/Y5qxzWMxY

Comment: @0___________ no `-Os` shouldn't be used unless you're optimizing for size. You need to use `-march` to generated code for a specific microarchitecture (vr4300 for N64) https://godbolt.org/z/r5oaEbxeh

Comment: @KazeEmanuar I couldn't see how you get that assembly, probably you're reading unoptimized assembly because gcc always generate an `addu` an a `subu`, not 2 `add`s. Compilers never use `add` and `sub` because they don't trap overflow. And there's no reason for N64 to run `mult` faster than the shift series gcc emitted. When I tune to N64 with the vr4300 CPU using `-march=vr4300` I got the same sequence: https://godbolt.org/z/r7oezGGY4

Comment: @phuclv N64 almost always is bandwidth bottlenecked so lesser instructions means a higher overall system speed, even if the individual instructions take longer to run. (memory shared between cpu and render)

even in that example code,
```
       addiu $5,$0,11
        mult $5 $4
        jr      $31
        mflo $2
```
would be 1 instruction less and be the desired outcome.
Turns out Os already does a decent job here and the issue was resolved that way.